# Can 'whenever' abilities trigger multiple times per turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say that I have an [Utvara Hellkite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUtvara%20Hellkite%5d) and 3 other dragons on the battlefield. Do I get a 6/6 Dragon for every Dragon that's attacking, or just one?

Comment: Someone has the Draconic Domination deck :P

Comment: Be careful using the word "activate" here. The proper question is "does it trigger multiple times"? To "activate" an ability is something you do to activated abilities, which are abilities with a cost, not a triggering condition.

Comment: They can trigger more than once, but whether they do or not depends on the specific wording. "*Whenever a Dragon you control attacks*" triggers for each attacking dragon, while "*Whenever Dragons you control attack*" only triggers once.

Answer (score 15):

On the card it says you get a 6/6 dragon token whenever a dragon you control attacks.

> 112.3c Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[Trigger condition], [effect],” and include (and
>   usually begin with) the word “when,” “whenever,” or “at.” **Whenever the
>   trigger event occurs**, the ability is put on the stack the next time a
>   player would receive priority and stays there until it’s countered, it
>   resolves, or it otherwise leaves the stack. See rule 603, “Handling
>   Triggered Abilities.”

So every time the trigger event occurs. But you can't activate abilities when attackers are being declared.

> 603.2a **Because they aren’t cast or activated**, triggered abilities can trigger even when it isn’t legal to cast spells and activate
>   abilities. Effects that preclude abilities from being activated don’t
>   affect them.

There are two types of abilities (that use the stack): activated abilities (which can also be loyalty abilities) and trigger abilities. Trigger abilities can trigger whenever; hence the word whenever/when.

> 603.2c An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. **However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains
>   multiple occurrences.** *Example: A permanent has an ability whose
>   trigger condition reads, “Whenever a land is put into a graveyard from
>   the battlefield, . . . .” If someone casts a spell that destroys all
>   lands, the ability will trigger once for each land put into the
>   graveyard during the spell’s resolution.*

For every occurrence. Even if no one can react between those occurrences.

So you get as many dragons as you attack with.

Comment: For extra clarification, if the ability were to create one dragon even if you attack with multiple, the wording would be "Whenever you attack with **one or more** dragons...", or something similar.